# Hide to a form using javascript

Tags: javascript

How do you set a forms display to `none` in javascript?

Comment: Please go through the tutorial given w3schools website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form doesn't have an `id` you can use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName( 'form' )[0].style.display = 'none';
```

If it does have an `id` use:

```
document.getElementById( 'idname' ).style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('form').style.display = 'none'
```

or with jQuery:

```
$('#form').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

To change a forms display to none, you select the form element by id and change the style to none.

Pure Javascript

```
document.getElementById("form-id").style.display = 'none';
```

JQuery

```
$('#form-id').css('display', 'none');
```